# Create LineMorph From 100@100 to mouse location in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm stuck with a simple thing i cant understand please help me out I'm really stuck

i need to create a `LineMorph` that will change dynamically 
start from point `100@100` To `mouse location`
how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your own morph subclass to handle mouse events. Or you can use a ready-made `HandleMorph`:

```
| line handle |
line := (LineMorph from: 100@100 to: 100@100 color: Color red width: 2) openInWorld.
handle := HandleMorph new forEachPointDo:
    [:newPoint | line setVertices: {100@100. newPoint}].
self currentHand attachMorph: handle.
```

Comment: Tnx man - i have one more question if you could help me i would be very happy -   i would like to activate a method after mouse click - what should i do ?

Comment: As I wrote, create your own morph. Do a tutorial, e.g. http://static.squeak.org/tutorials/morphic-tutorial-1.html And if you get stuck again, post a proper question.